# Why all the minus sign in the velocity?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

According to Misner, Thorne and Wheeler (Gravitation pag 893 eq. (33.13b)) the 4-velocity of a stationary observer in a Kerr-Newman black hole is given by:
$$u=\dfrac{\xi_t+\Omega \xi_\phi}{\sqrt{-g_{tt}-2\Omega g_{t\phi}-\Omega^2 g_{\phi\phi}}}$$
where $\xi_t=\partial/\partial t$ and $\xi_\phi=\partial/\partial\phi$ are the Killing vectors.

I do not understand the minus in front of the $\Omega^2g_{\phi\phi}$ coefficient, I would have said it was $+\Omega g_{\phi\phi}$: where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

MTW uses a $(-+++)$ metric signature (like sane people do ;-) ). Hence timelike vectors have a negative norm. Consequently, the quantity inside the square root is minus the norm of the vector in the numerator (to ensure that $u$ has norm $-1$).